# Radarchart Using fmsb in R

Tags: r, radar-chart

I was trying to make a `radarchart` using `fmsb` but I'm having some trouble with my script.

If anyone can help I will be really appreciated.

my radarchart sequence must be between (0,2) and by 0.2.
But when I try it the graph it is out of bounds.
my script:

```
library("fmsb")
```

data:

```
df <- data.frame("hours" = 0:23, 
  "max_value" = 2,"min_value" = 0,"CallsProportion" = (c(1.583333333
,1.291666667,1.166666667,1,0.041666667,0.833333333,0.625
,0.791666667,0.75,0.458333333,0.833333333,0.625,0.708333333,0.458333333,0.291666667,0.416666667,0.625,0.458333333,1.208333333,2.375,2.166666667,2.208333333,1.625,1.541666667)))

radarchart(df, axistype = 1,
       caxislabels = seq(0,2,0.2), 
       cglcol = "grey",
       vlcex = 0.8, cglty = 1, 
       cglwd = 0.5,axislabcol = "grey", 
       pcol = "black",plwd = 1.8, plty = 1)
```

[image: radarchart]

Comment: We do not have access to the data file. Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(G.chrys)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(G.chrys, 25))`.

Comment: Thanks for that Monic. I typed my data.frame. Hope you can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a data format problem. Function `fmsb::radarchart` needs an object of class `"data.frame"` as first argument, a `"matrix"` won't do it. From `help("radarchart")`:

> The data frame to be used to draw `radarchart`. If `maxmin` is `TRUE`,
>   this must include maximum values as row 1 and minimum values as row 2
>   for each variables, and actual data should be given as row 3 and lower
>   rows. The number of columns (variables) must be more than 2.

Note that `maxmin = TRUE` is the default setting.

So follow these steps.

1. Get the range of values, their minimum and maximum.
2. Create a matrix with 2 rows and as many columns as columns in the original data frame.
3. Bind the matrix with the data rows.
4. Set the column names to the first column of `df`, column `hours`.

In this case there is just one vector to plot, vector `CallsProportion`.

```
r <- range(df$CallsProportion)
m <- matrix(r[2:1], nrow = 2, ncol = nrow(df))
df2 <- rbind.data.frame(m, df$CallsProportion)
names(df2) <- df$hours

radarchart(df2, axistype = 1,
           caxislabels = seq(0, 2, 0.2), 
           cglcol = "grey",
           vlcex = 0.8, cglty = 1, 
           cglwd = 0.5, axislabcol = "grey", 
           pcol = "black", plwd = 1.8, plty = 1)
```

[image]